# Set a global variable only once in golang

Tags: go

I have a main.go file which has:

```
// running the router in port 9000
func main() {
    router := routers.InitApp()
    router.RunTLS(":9000" , "domain.crt" , "domain.key")
}
```

In another gofile I have

```
package utils
var ConfigMap = GetAppConfig
func GetAppConfig() map[string]string{
 ....//
}
```

ConfigMap being a global variable , everytime I try to access `utils.ConfigMap` map the `GetAppConfig` function is called. How can I call this function only once while by app initializes and then access the ConfigMap anyehere I want in the go project.

Comment: How about to declare in init function?

Answer (score 22):

This is what package [`init()`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization) functions are for. They are executed once, before your package can be reached "from the outside":

```
var ConfigMap map[string]string

func init() {
    // Init ConfigMap here
}
```

Note that such exported global variables should be protected if you want to allow concurrent use. It would be unfeasible to leave this to the users of the package.

For this purpose, you should declare `ConfigMap` unexported:

```
var configMap[string]string
```

And provide a getter function which would properly protect it with a [`Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex):

```
var confMu = &sync.Mutex{}

func Config(name string) string {
    confMu.Lock()
    defer confMu.Unlock()
    return configMap[name]
}
```

Comment: So a variable declaration (non exported) an init function and the Config function in the go file? and then to access the configMap variable in other files how do we do that? I cannot do utils.configMap I think

Comment: @love2code Yes, and in this case you could not access `configMap`. But you could query any config value with the `Config()` function, safely.

Comment: well when I run my application configMap is initialised perfectly. But later when I try to print the configMap while calling Config() function it is empty.

Comment: @love2code Most likely you are printing another map, or you are not synchronizing access to the map. Impossible to tell without seeing more of your code.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/w6BIh_plmZ Here is my code and in one of my functions outside this package I do `x := utils.Config("key1")
 fmt.Println(x)`

Comment: @love2code Inside the `Config()` function, if you want to print the `configMap`, that also has to happen after locking the mutex! Also you don't need the comma-ok idiom, if a key is not in the map, the value of the index expression `configMap[key]` will be the empty `string`, exactly what you return anyway.

Comment: @love2code And the main reason is that in your `init()` function you are filling / populating a local `configMap` variable and NOT the global variable! Remove this line from `init()`: `var configMap = map[string]string{}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118631/discussion-between-love2code-and-icza).

Comment: It means inside the `init` function we don't have to mutex lock or unlock? because `init` run once before the main function, there's no concern about concurrency, right?

Comment: @TomSawyer App and package initialization runs in a single goroutine, so there is no need for synchronization, unless you manually launch goroutines from `init()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a typo in the code that you posted. You define the configMap outside the init function like this:

```
var configMap map[string]string
```

This is fine but inside the init you also have this:

```
var configMap = map[string]string{}
```

Here you are shadowing the configMap that you have outside the `init` function meaning that you have declared the variable again inside the `init`. As a result when you access the variable outside of the `init` function you will get the global variable which is still empty. If you remove the `var` inside the `init` it would work fine.

```
configMap = map[string]string{}
```

[Here's](https://play.golang.org/p/5LbDwosC2S) a quick demonstration.

There is another typo in the original question:

```
var configMap = GetAppConfig
```

This should be:

```
var configMap = GetAppConfig()
```

You are assigning the function to a variable rather than result of the function.